# How to get proof rules with pseudo-code in them?

Tags: algorithms, logic

I wish to typeset some deduction rules for Hoare logic as sequents with the pseudo-code using the `algorithmic` package. I have tried using `\frac{}{}`, but then e.g. `if then else` gets flattened. I have also tried `bussproofs`. Again the pseudo-code was flattened to one line.

What would be a good way to get (with a shorter hline of course)

{ I ∧ B } S { I }

---

{ I }

```
while B do
  S
od
```

{ I ∧ ¬ B }

What I've been seeing with my efforts up to now was similar to

{ I ∧ B } S { I }

---

{ I } while B do Sod { I ∧ ¬ B }

Now, I'm experimenting with putting the bottom Hoare-triple in a minipage.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{bussproofs}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicendwhile}{{\bf od}}
\newcommand{\textmath}[1]{\text{\it #1}}

\newenvironment{Condition}{\{\,}{\,\}\;}
\newenvironment{Pseudocode}{\begin{algorithmic}}{\end{algorithmic}}
\newcommand{\hoareTripleMM}[3]{\{\,#1\,\}\;#2\;\{\,#3\,\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{\(\hoareTripleMM{V}{\textmath{init}}{I}\)}
    \AxiomC{\(\hoareTripleMM{I \land B}{S}{I}\)}
    \AxiomC{\((I \land \neg B) \implies P\)}
    \RightLabel{(W2)}
    \TrinaryInfC{
      \begin{minipage}{68pt}
        \(
        \begin{Condition}
          V
        \end{Condition}\)
        \begin{Pseudocode}
          \STATE \(\textmath{init}\) 
          \WHILE{\(B\)} \(S\) \ENDWHILE
        \end{Pseudocode}
        \(
        \begin{Condition}
          P
        \end{Condition}\)
      \end{minipage}
    }
  \end{prooftree}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There are still some issues:

1. There is vertical space between the pre-condition and the pseudo-code that I do not yet know where it comes from.
2. There is a LaTeX error: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." that only occurs when the `Pseudocode` clock is in there.
3. I'd like the width of the `minipage` to be taken from the width of the pseudo-code.

I'd like to use `algorithmic` if that's possible, since I am already using that package quite a bit.

Comment: What do you mean with "if then else get flattened"? Could you provide a minimal example of what you have so far, pointing out what is wrong with it?

Comment: The "missing `\item`" error goes away if you put `\STATE` in front of `\(S\)`. It's not clear what output you're expecting.

Comment: @egreg: thanks for the hint. The output is now almost what I wanted, but I didn't want the vertical space between the pre-condition and the pseudo-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `algorithmic` environment is just a `list`, so it's typeset to the current line width. Thus it's not possible to avoid specifying the width of the `minipage`.

In order to avoid the big space, just add `\endgraf` after the first element:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\renewcommand{\algorithmicendwhile}{{\bf od}}
\newcommand{\textmath}[1]{\text{\it #1}}

\newenvironment{Condition}{\{\,}{\,\}\;}
\newenvironment{Pseudocode}{\algorithmic}{\endalgorithmic}
\newcommand{\hoareTripleMM}[3]{\{\,#1\,\}\;#2\;\{\,#3\,\}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{prooftree}
    \AxiomC{\(\hoareTripleMM{V}{\textmath{init}}{I}\)}
    \AxiomC{\(\hoareTripleMM{I \land B}{S}{I}\)}
    \AxiomC{\((I \land \neg B) \implies P\)}
    \RightLabel{(W2)}
    \TrinaryInfC{%
      \begin{minipage}{68pt}
        \(
        \begin{Condition}
          V
        \end{Condition}\)\endgraf
        \begin{Pseudocode}
          \STATE \(\textmath{init}\) 
          \WHILE{\(B\)} \STATE \(S\) \ENDWHILE
        \end{Pseudocode}
        \(
        \begin{Condition}
          P
        \end{Condition}\)
      \end{minipage}%
    }
  \end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

One has to use `\endgraf` because the `\TrinaryInfC` macro chokes when `\par` is in its argument.

[image]

Comment: Looks good! Would it be possible to save the `algorithmic` environment to a box, trim off whitespace on the right, and then determine the width of the resulting box?

Comment: @Marko Sorry, no: the lines are the whole `\linewidth` long. It *may* be possible to dismantle the box and every line in it, getting only the text. For such a tiny bit of text it's simply more convenient to type it directly without `algorithmic`, I'd say.